# Does Mongodb have a special value that's ignored in queries?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My web application runs on MongoDB, using python and pyMongo.  I get this scenario a lot - code that reads something like:

```
from pymongo import Connnection
users = Connection().db.users

def findUsers(firstName=None, lastName=None, age=None):
    criteria = {}
    if firstName:
        criteria['firstName'] = firstName
    if lastName:
        criteria['lastName'] = lastName
    if age:
        criteria['age'] = age
    query = users.find(criteria)
    return query
```

I find that kind of messy how I need an `if` statement for every value that's optional to figure out if it's needs to go into the search criteria.  If only there were a special query value that mongo ignored in queries.  Then my code could look like this:

```
def findUsers(firstName=<ignored by mongo>, lastName=<ignored by mongo>, age=<ignored by mongo>):
    query = users.find({'firstName':firstName, 'lastName':lastName, 'age':age})
    return query
```

Now isn't that so much cleaner than before, especially if you have many more optional parameters.  Any parameters that aren't specified default to something mongo just ignores.  Is there any way to do this?  Or at-least something more concise than what I currently have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably better off filtering your empty values in Python. You don't need a separate if-statement for each of your values. The local variables can be accessed by `locals()`, so you can create a dictionary by filtering out all keys with `None` value.

```
def findUsers(firstName=None, lastName=None, age=None):
    loc = locals()
    criteria = {k:loc[k] for k in loc if loc[k] != None}
    query = users.find(criteria)
```

Note that this syntax uses dictionary comprehensions, introduced in Python 2.7. If you're running an earlier version of Python, you need to replace that one line with

```
criteria = dict((k, loc[k]) for k in loc if loc[k] != None)
```

Comment: Oh that's brilliant.  I didn't know that comprehensions worked for dictionaries, or that you can have an `if` statement in a comprehension.  My only issue is that you have to ensure `locals()` is called before any local declarations, otherwise it might return unwanted variables in a more complicated function.  Is there a method that just returns local function arguments?

Comment: What you could do is use a positional argument list: `def findUsers(**args): ...` and then use the `args` dictionary inside the function. If you call the function with `findUsers(firstName='Tom', age=25)`, the `args` dictionary will look like `{'firstName':'Tom', 'age':25}`.

Comment: ok, that's a reasonable solution in some cases, but I like how defined arguments provide an abstraction to the programmer.  I guess I'll just use the first solution and make a comment that says "keep this on the first line"